# Subscripted min operator with two variables

Tags: discrete-mathematics

In my discreet computational mathematics book, they use the following syntax without explaining its meaning:

$\min_{(x,y)}$

**EDIT**

In context: $dist(v) = \min_{(u,v)\in E} \{dist(u) + l(u,v)\}$, where $E$ is the set of edges between nodes in an acyclic graph, $l(u,v)$ is the weight of an edge between vertices $u$ and $v$ and $dist(u)$ is the best known distance from the source.

Comment: Is it supposed to look like that?

Comment: Yeah. Thanks. I didn't realize I had to close it with a $.

Comment: Can you give us a bit of context here?  It's really hard to comment on notation that is non-standard without seeing it in use

Comment: Here you go. Some more context. Sorry.

Comment: I misread it! The element-of and E are also part of the subscript!

Comment: I think it is saying that the distance to v is the smallest of the distances from the source to any node that has an edge from u to v plus the distance from u to v.

Answer (score 0):

In your context, $\min\limits_{(u,v) \in E}$ means that the minimization is done over the set of pair of vertices $(u,v)$ which have an edge between them.